# Oracle Apex tabular from based on collection multi row delete

Tags: javascript, oracle, collections, oracle-apex, tabular

I have a tabular form based on a collection like below,

```
    APEX_COLLECTION.ADD_MEMBER(
      p_collection_name => 'MPL_COLL',
      p_c001            => :P97_UPC,
      p_c002            => '10',
      p_n001            => 2);
```

I have created an additional check_box column which is an indicator for deletion. 
[image]

If the check_box on the heading(id = "selectall") is checked, all the check_boxes for each row will be checked as well done by the following javascript in a dynamic action.

```
// Process for select all Y checkbox
$("#selectall").change(function(){  //"select all" change 

//iterate through all checkboxes to tick
$("[data-col='delete']").each(function(ii)
{ 

   var check_id = $("[data-col='delete']").get(ii).id.substring(0,8); 


   if ($("#selectall").prop('checked') )
   {
       // ticking    
       $("#"+check_id ).prop('checked', true ) ;  
       $("#"+check_id ).val('Y') ;   
   }
   else
   {
       //unticking
       $("#"+check_id ).prop('checked', false ) ; 
       $("#"+check_id ).val('N') ;
   }

});    //end each checkbox      

});
```

Then I have a process (on submit after validation) which is triggered by a delete button, that does the following plsql

```
   DECLARE
   v_seq NUMBER;
   v_collection_name   VARCHAR2 (30) := 'MPL_COLL';
BEGIN
   for i in 1..apex_application.g_f03.count
   loop
      v_seq := apex_application.g_f02(i);   
      apex_debug_message.log_message(p_message => 'seq#: '|| apex_application.g_f02(i), 
                                     p_level => 3);                                   
      apex_debug_message.log_message(p_message => 'UPC: '||apex_application.g_f03(i) || ' and delete_flag is ' || apex_application.g_f06(i), 
                                     p_level => 3);
      if apex_application.g_f06(i) = 'Y' then                                     
        apex_collection.delete_member (p_collection_name      => v_collection_name,
                                       p_seq                  => v_seq
                                      );   
      end if;                            
   end loop; 

END;
```

The issue I had is, when I click the check_box on the heading, which checks all the check_boxes for each row, 
[image]

and click the delete button, no record in the collection is deleted, this is what I got in the log,

[image]

Looks like it's because it wouldn't sumbit the page,

Can anyone give me some advice please? How do I remove the member from the collection based on whether the check_box is checked or not?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hopefully you've solved this by now?
If not, have you considered adding an apex debug message to show the value for apex_application.g_f03.count?  Also, are you sure that's the right collection to check for what's changed?